# Normal Submagma?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, magma

*Is there a definition of normal submagma?* visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)

For normal sub-quasi-group I found two:

1. A sub-quasi-group $H$ is called normal if there exists a normal congruence $\theta$ such that $H$ coincides with one of the congruence classes.
2. A sub-quasi-group $H$ of a quasi-group $(Q,.)$ is called normal if and only if $x.H=H.x$, $(x.y).H=x.(y.H)$ and $H.(x.y)=(H.x).y$, for all $x,y\in Q$.

*If this is true and the two definitions are equivalent, then how to prove that the first definition gives the second one?*

Comment: Most-recent repost of these questions: http://mathoverflow.net/q/210716/1916, http://mathoverflow.net/q/210702/1916

Comment: What does x.H stand for?  Is "." an operation?

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood: $.$ is the quasigroup operation as in $(Q,.)$

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: the first one of your links is obsolete and the second...doesn't it show a cross-posting?...

Answer (score 1):

There is a definition of **normal subset** (of a semigroup) at page 24 of [*A Survey of Binary Systems*](https://books.google.it/books/about/A_survey_of_binary_systems.html?id=skwfAQAAIAAJ&hl=it) by R.H. Bruck:

> If $\theta$ is a homomorphism of a semigroup $S$ into a groupoid, the
>   image $S\theta=S'$ is also a semigroup. If $s'$ is an element of $S'$,
>   let $K=s'\theta^{-1}$ be the inverse image of $s'$; that is,
>   $K$ is the set of all $s$ in $S$ such that $s\theta=s'$. Clearly $K$
>   has the following properties:
>
> 1. if $k\in K$, $x\in S$ and $xk\in K$, then $xK\subset K$;
> 2. if $k\in K$, $x\in S$ and $kx\in K$, then $Kx\subset K$;
> 3. if $k\in K$, $x,y\in S$ and $xky\in K$, then $xKy\subset K$;
>
> A non-empty subset $K$ of $S$ with properties 1., 2., 3. is called a **normal** subset.

This is followed by a reflection about why the study of normal subsets (subgroupoids) is less interesting than normal subsemigroups (or subgroups):

> To a given normal subset $K$ of $S$ there may correspond two (or more) distinct homomorphisms of $S$ with $K$ as an inverse image; herein resides, perhaps, the relative poverty of the theory.

Comment: I agree with you that the study of normal subgroupoid is less interesting than normal subsemigroup , but I need to know if there is any definition of **normal subgroupoid (or sub-quasigroup)**. In deed I'm using Bruck books in my research and there is nothing about normal subgroupoid.